# Having trouble with building Docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a docker image for a software using `docker build -t cytools .`

Here is the output that I'm confused about:

```
[+] Building 0.0s (1/2)                                                         
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2B                                         0.0s
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount346931491/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

Does anyone know what this means? I am new to all this, so sorry if I didn't use the correct terminology or give the full picture!

Comment: Hello! Can you update your question with a few more details please? For example can you show the dockerfile you are using?

Comment: From the command prompt, please perform an `ls` or `dir` in that same directory to show that `Dockerfile` exists, has a capital `D` and no extension.

Comment: Thank you, I think your comments resolved the issue! The dockerfile wasn't in the same directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the Dockerfile is not in the path, '.' means the current directory you are in.